# Android AchartEngine how to generate combined graph?

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

I would like to ask, how to create combined horizontal scrollable graph like on the image below using AchartEngine library?:

[image]

Many Thanks for any sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `XYCombinedChart` having a `BarChart` and a `LineChart`. An example for doing something similar would be [this](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/CombinedTemperatureChart.java).